# Male cats or dogs resist men and female one resist women, is that true?

Tags: dogs, cats

Is it true that male cats or dogs welcome women more than men, and vice versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't true. A cat or dog that has lived solely with one gender of human may consider the other a strange and threatening beast until it has learned otherwise, but that's a matter of how that particular animal was (or wasn't) socialized, unrelated to the gender of the pet.